# Ionic ion-searchbar increase size of clear icon

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

is there a way to increase the ***size*** of the `clearIcon` on `ion-search` component?

```
 <ion-card-content>
  <ion-searchbar
    mode="ios"
    autocomplete="off"
    autocorrect="off"
    spellcheck="false"
    animated="true"
    debounce="500"
    clearIcon="close"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    [(ngModel)]="search"
    (ionChange)="runSearch()"
  ></ion-searchbar>
</ion-card-content>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to `global.scss`, changing the width value as per your requirement

```
.searchbar-clear-icon {
    width: 30px !important;
}
```